# Emacs yank behavior changed - how to get old behavior back?

Tags: emacs, selection, paste

This is on Linux (Ubuntu), working with emacs -nw in an xterm.
GNU Emacs 26.3

Until recently I had two copy & paste mechanisms available:

1. kill some text using ^K (`kill-line`), it would go to the kill-ring,
   and could be retrieved using ^Y (`yank`)
2. select some text, possibly in another window, maybe in emacs or firefox,
   using the left mouse button, it would go to some X selection buffer,
   and could be retrieved using the middle mouse button.

These two channels worked entirely independent of each other.

Nowadays pasting a mouse selection pollutes the emacs kill-ring,
or at least after mouse-pasting some text a yank also pastes that same text.

How can I teach emacs again not to change the kill-ring and use the unchanged kill-ring upon yank, independent of any mouse pasting?
I tried a few combinations of `(setq select-enable-clipboard t)` and `(setq select-enable-primary nil)` but did not hit a successful .emacs incantation.

Comment: Somewhere in your X Clipboard settings, untick "Synchronize clipboards" or whatever name that option has in your Window Manager.

Comment: My window manager is twm. The string [Cc]lipboard does not occur in .twmrc. Also, note that I do *not* want to synchronize these two separate channels.

Comment: That's why I suggested to *un*tick the option (the name was taken from my LXDE clipboard). I have no idea how to configure the clipboard behaviour in twm.

Comment: This is an emacs question. Emacs should use its kill buffer upon a yank, and nothing else. A window manager does not write into emacs' data structures. No window manager behavior is involved (I think).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(setq interprogram-paste-function (lambda () nil))
```

If you've added something to the X11 clipboard, `yank` will try to insert that instead of the top of the kill ring using `interprogram-paste-function`.  If `i-p-f` returns `nil`, it will use the top of `kill-ring`.

When I run a terminal Emacs, `gui-selection-value` always returns `nil` anyway, so I'm not sure why yours doesn't.

---

Looking at the source, `(setq select-enable-clipboard nil select-enable-primary nil)` should achieve the same result.